# errno 98 but no other mongod running

Tags: mongodb

Here are my config options:

```
options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf"
, net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.57" }
, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }
, storage: { dbPath: "/data" }
, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/log/mongod.log" } 
}
```

First thing I do is check to see if any mongod is running using

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

I see no results as expected (I've run sudo chkconfig mongod off to make sure the service doesn't start at boot).

When I run

```
sudo mongod service start
```

And check /log/mongod.log I see this

```
getaddrinfo(" 10.0.2.57") failed: Name or service not known
ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
```

I then run this

```
netstat -an | grep :27017
```

And get no results. So then I check to see if a mongod is running using

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

I get get no results.

When I remove my 10.0.2.57 from the config file the service starts and I can connect to it.

Do I need to explicitly have that 10.0.2.57 in my conf file to allow external connections to mongo? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: I'm very weak with Linux.

Comment: The first thing I would try is removing the space between the comma and the second IP. It does not appear to be gracefully handled by mongod.

Comment: I would also run "netstat -an |grep 27017" rather than "netstat -an |grep :27017" to confirm whether the port is in use.

Comment: @JamesWahlin I typically put : when searching for ports because if I'm searching for ssh and don't include the : then I'll get any instance of 22 included, like 10.22.0.55:1000 would be there - just a habit.

Comment: @JamesWahlin I removed the space before the ip and it worked. The weird thing is that I can't start the service using sudo service mongod start anymore, I have to use sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: The service script will start mongod under its own user. I would take a look at the data files and make sure none are owned by root, which would be the case if created when running mongod directly with sudo. If not the case take a look at the mongod log file which may provide clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between the comma and the second IP. It does not look like mongod is handling gracefully.